# Calculate the centroid and mass moment of intertia of a prism

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, volume, centroid

I am wondering if there is a "trick" I can use to ease the equation level for this problem.

Say I have a solid (constant density) prism which is bounded by the following 6 "planes" (I use subscript to mark the different functions, function "i" doesn't sound correct). 
$$y_0 = 0$$
$$y_1 = C$$
$$x_0 = f_0(y)$$
$$x_1 = f_1(y)$$
$$z_0 = f_2(x, y)$$
$$z_1 = f_3(x, y)$$

So basically the prism has parallel vertical sides in the x-z projection, 2 more sides are vertical, and the last pair are in a "near horizontal" plane.

Now the moment the centroid (shown for x only here) is calculated using
$$m = \rho \iiint_E \mathrm{dV} = \rho \int_0^{C}\int_{f_0}^{f_1}\int_{f_2}^{f_3}\mathrm{dz \ dx \ dy}$$
$$\bar{x} = \frac{\rho \iiint_Ex \mathrm{dV}}{m} = \frac{ \int_0^{C}\int_{f_0}^{f_1}\int_{f_2}^{f_3}x \ \mathrm{dz \ dx \ dy}} { \int_0^{C}\int_{f_0}^{f_1}\int_{f_2}^{f_3}\mathrm{dz \ dx \ dy}}$$

Now to get the moment of inertia I shift the axis system, so I get new functions for the planes. and then solve:
$$I_x = \rho \iiint_E(y^2 + z^2) \mathrm{dV} =  \int_{0 - \bar{y}}^{C - \bar{y}}\int_{f_0(y + \bar{y}) - \bar{x}}^{f_1(y + \bar{y}) - \bar{x} }\int_{f_2(x + \bar{x}, y + \bar{y}) - \bar{z}}^{f_3(x  + \bar{x},y + \bar{y}) - \bar{z}}(y^2 + z^2)  \mathrm{dz \ dx \ dy}$$

Now I wonder, is this "long winded road" the easiest? Or can I take a shortcut (IE: not calculate centroid/ignore it). Also my colleguea should've brought me the numbers, but I haven't received them - is there a way to calculate this & make a formula I can fit into a script? Considering everything is a linear function

Comment: Are each of the three sets of nonadjacent faces parallel?

Comment: @travis: no, only the "first two" (which should be obvious). I do know that the two faces in the x-z plane have the same shape & orientation (though different dimensions and complete different location on the x-z plane).